# Composer. Errror: "Could not parse version constraint..." on valid composer.json

Tags: composer-php

Problem: Get Could not parse version constraint on valid composer.json.

I have **/srv/www/site/api/composer.json** and **/srv/www/site/frontend/composer.json**. No **composer.lock** or **vendor/** in catalogs /srv/www/site/api/ and /srv/www/site/frontend/

Api composer.json and frontend composer.json contain the same text:

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require":
    {
        "doctrine/dbal": "*"
    },
    "autoload":
    {
        "psr-4":
        {
            "app\\": "./"
        }
    }
}
```

First. I run.

```
cd /srv/www/site/api
composer install
```

And get result. All right.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.2.7)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.4.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/common (v2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.5.2)
    Loading from cache

doctrine/dbal suggests installing symfony/console (For helpful console commands such as SQL execution and import of files.)
Generating autoload files
noopic@WhiteBear:/srv/www/dev.laronet.ee/api$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

Second. I run.

```
cd /srv/www/site/frontend
composer install
```

And get result. Error.

```
  [UnexpectedValueException]                                       
  Could not parse version constraint >: Invalid version string ""  



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

How fix it? This is bug or my fail?

Composer version f85d965732d9505b69242a070dc0b381c9f6bbab

Answer (score 0):

Just remove .composer folder in user catalog. For me **/home/noopic/.composer**. Install successfully in two catalogs.

But if i run in frontend

```
composer update
```

get same error.